# How to enable the Developer Preview version of Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to test the Calling API of Teams, when enabling Calling Bot function in App Studio, there is a hint as below:

```
Calling endpoint
Manage the calling endpoint for your bot here.
(This feature is in beta and only available for users using the Developer Preview version of Teams.)
```

So I got below link to help enable Developer Preview version of Teams, but there is no the `About → Developer preview` menu.

```
//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-intro

Enabling uploading of apps in the admin console of your tenant as described here.
Click on your profile (either in the upper right or lower left of the Teams interface) to display the Teams menu.
Select About → Developer preview.
Select Switch to Developer preview.
```

[image: Enable uploading custom app]

[image: 'About' menu in my Teams App]

Has the method been changed, or I haven't the right way?

Comment: Did you already try to click on the profile icon to access the 'About' menu? Or only the menu of your screenshot.

Comment: @Mick the 'Ablout' menu is only the 5 displays of my screenshot on Teams App.

Comment: Did you update the setup policy to allow upload custom apps recently? Sometimes it can take a while for that setting to reflect to the client. Could you please try logging out and back in?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Thanks, as your suggest, It has been enabled.

Comment: I had to logout/login on the Microsoft Teams desktop app after enabling **Upload custom apps** on **Team Apps -> Setup policies** on the [**Microsoft Teams admin center**](https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/dashboard) to see the Developer Preview option.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable it by clicking your profile, like below.[image]

the teams version I am using is "1.2.00.24753", Please ensure that you are using the relevant version of Teams client, and if some setting was changed in Admin Console, you can log-in again to make it work.

Comment: The setting has time-delay and it need to logging out and back in, As above suggest, It has been normal, Thank You.

Comment: cuz of synchronization stuff, fews of setting should be tme-delay. so log out and back in often solves our issue, :)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Developer Preview in Teams via changing the Teams policies from Admin Center.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to open Update policies settings and set the policy you want to use to "Enabled" (the default is "Follow Office Preview").
[enter image description here][1]

[1]: [MS Teams Update policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UytG.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).